# net 7 integration tests - test specific ConfigureTestServices?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0

I'm using `ConfigureTestServices` to mock out some of my dependencies for integration tests. Works fine. But I would like to have different mocks of `IFileSystem` for different tests, how can I replace it on test level? I still want to utilize the IoC container.

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            var fileSystemMock = new Mock<IFileSystem>();
            // fileSystemMock.Setup...
            services.AddScoped<IFileSystem>(_ => fileSystemMock.Object);
        });
    }
}
```

Here's my test:

```
public class MyTests
{
        private CustomWebApplicationFactory _factory = null!;
        private IServiceScope _scope = null!;
    
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _factory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory();
            _scope = _factory.Services.CreateScope();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _factory.Dispose();
            _scope.Dispose();
        }


        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            // ClassToTest has IFileSystem injected
            // How can I add a test specific mock of it for this test?
            var service = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ClassToTest>();
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to achieve what you want, one way would be to accept IFileSystem as a constructor parameter in your CustomWebApplicationFactory, that way your tests can pass in their own instance of the IFileSystem mock

Comment: @SelmirAljic Gooa idea, thanks. Is there any way to replace an implementation on the ServiceProvider? I was expecting to find something like `_scope.ServiceProvider.Replace`

Comment: As far as I know the default .Net di container does not support it, autofac has something called lifetime scopes where you can do exactly that.

Comment: Another approach you could take is use a Moq feature. You fetch an instance of IFileSystem using the service scope and then you do Mock.Get(fileSystemInstance) which will give you the mock which you can then setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways this problem can be solved and here are a few examples:

1. Injecting the `IFileSystem` mock as a constructor parameter
2. Resolving the registered `IFileSystem` using `IServiceProvider` and setting it up using `Mock.Get(fileSystemInstance).Setup(...)`
3. Using `CustomWebApplicationFactory` as a base class for the tests and making the `ConfigureTestServices` call overridable

Comment: There's no ``CustomWebApplicationFactory`` to inherit from ("use as a base class" like you suggest). 

Maybe you meant to say create "``CustomWebApplicationFactory`` and inherit from ``WebApplicationFactory``"?

Comment: @RobertMrobo I actually meant the `CustomWebApplicationFactory` in the code snippet from the question itself, since it’s doing exactly that what you mentioned